# How to define multiple CVS ROOT?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cvs

I had one CVS repository located in a remote location, which CVS can access via these environment variables:

```
export CVSROOT=:ext:xyz@abc.com:/home/xyz/cvsroot
export CVS_RSH=ssh
export CVS_SERVER=cvs
```

Recently I added another server which has a different location and a different repository. I tried adding the location via

```
export CVSROOT=$CVSROOT:ext:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot
```

However, I am unable to perform operations such as checkout and update with the following error:

```
Cannot access /home/xyz/cvsroot:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot
No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what "it" is when you say "it doesn't seem to work", but based on your original variables, you probably want `export CVSROOT=":ext:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot"` instead.

Comment: Sorry, my language was unclear, I updated the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in a CVS repository, any cvs operations will take its CVSROOT information from the  current directory's `CVS/Root` file, regardless of what any `CVSROOT` environment variables are there. So your only issue is how to initially checkout from your different repositories.

When you type `export CVSROOT=$CVSROOT:ext:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot` that says "change the CVSROOT environment variable to be the old variable with ':ext:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot' appended to the end if it. That's likely not what you want. You need to take the `$CVSROOT` out of the right hand side.

As a workable workflow, you can either

- run `cvs -d <newcvsroot> co <reponame>` to specify each CVSROOT as you do your `cvs co` (you may need to `unset CVS_RSH` as well, I don't know about that), or
- you could also `export CVSROOT=<newcvsroot>; unset CVS_RSH; cvs co <reponame>`.

If you're frequently checking out from multiple repositories, you may want to have environment variables set up like this, and then you can easily check out from each repo. (Add repos as necessary.)

```
# in your .bashrc or someting
export REPO1ROOT=:ext:xyz@fgh.com:/cvs/cvsroot
export REPO2ROOT=:ext:xyz@abc.com:/home/xyz/cvsroot
export CVSROOT=$REPO1ROOT # default

# when you use the command line
cvs co repo1
cvs -d $REPO2ROOT co repo2
```

Comment: Excellent! That solves my problem very well. Thank you! I (wrongly) assumed that we need to define CVSROOT while updating the repositories as well, so that CVS knows where to update them from.